# kmalloc-256 がメモリを消費しているようです。これを解放する方法はあるのでしょうか?

Tags: linux, memory-leaks

([英語版の StackOverflow で同様の質問をしました](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47131599/kmalloc-256-seems-taking-most-of-the-memory-resource-how-can-i-free-this)が、回答がつかないので、日本語版でも質問させてください)

Jenkins を動かしている Linux インスタンスがあります (Amazon Linux `Linux ip-xxx 4.9.20-11.31.amzn1.x86_64 #1`)。ここで動いている Jenkins のジョブがメモリ不足で失敗することがよくあります。

`free` や `/proc/meminfo` などを眺めると、スラブがメモリの大半を消費しているようにみえます。

```
[root@ip-xxx ~]# free -tm
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7985       7205        779          0         19        310
-/+ buffers/cache:       6876       1108
Swap:            0          0          0
Total:        7985       7205        779

[root@ip-xxx ~]# cat /proc/meminfo | grep "Slab\|claim"
Slab:            6719244 kB
SReclaimable:      34288 kB
SUnreclaim:      6684956 kB
```

`echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` のようにして、スラブから `dentry` を解放するテクニックなどは調べることができたのですが、ここで大量にメモリを確保している `kmalloc-256` はどうすればいいのでしょうか? もしくは、どのプロセスが `kmalloc-256` を握っているかを調べる方法はあるでしょうか?

```
[root@ip-xxx ~]# slabtop -o | head -n 15
 Active / Total Objects (% used)    : 26805556 / 26816810 (100.0%)
 Active / Total Slabs (% used)      : 837451 / 837451 (100.0%)
 Active / Total Caches (% used)     : 85 / 111 (76.6%)
 Active / Total Size (% used)       : 6696903.08K / 6701323.05K (99.9%)
 Minimum / Average / Maximum Object : 0.01K / 0.25K / 8.00K

  OBJS ACTIVE  USE OBJ SIZE  SLABS OBJ/SLAB CACHE SIZE NAME                   
26658528 26658288  99%    0.25K 833079       32   6664632K kmalloc-256            
 21624  21009  97%    0.12K    636       34      2544K kernfs_node_cache      
 20055  20055 100%    0.19K    955       21      3820K dentry                 
 10854  10646  98%    0.58K    402       27      6432K inode_cache            
 10624   9745  91%    0.03K     83      128       332K kmalloc-32             
  7395   7395 100%    0.05K     87       85       348K ftrace_event_field     
  6912   6384  92%    0.02K     27      256       108K kmalloc-16             
  6321   5581  88%    0.19K    301       21      1204K cred_jar
```

Comment: メモリリークで解放されていないのではないでしょうか？
普通に ps, top コマンドなどで 6GB 以上使用しているプロセスはありませんでしょうか？
プロセスじゃないとすると、kernel スレッドかもしれません。
kernel モジュールを追加していませんでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。実はこの質問文を作ったあとで、どうにもこうにもならなくてマシンを再起動して難をのがれてしまい、今はメモリに余裕がある状態なのですが (ただ、またじわーっと `kmalloc-256` が増えてきている)、このときは `ps` や `top` などで大量にメモリを確保しているものはなかったはずです。デフォルトでない kernel モジュールを追加してはいないのですが、仮に kernel スレッドがメモリリークを引き起こしている場合、どう対処するのがよいのでしょうか?

Answer (score 1):

「[サーバーのメモリが少しずつ圧迫される原因と対策を調べてみた](https://qiita.com/bezeklik/items/7e1ac9e5da39261be7bd) 」の記事が参考になると思います。

Comment: どうもありがとうございます。

まさにこの記事を読んで `dentry` は解放できたのですが、それ以外 (たとえば、この場合は `kmalloc-...`) はどうすればいいのかと思いました。

Comment: kmallocはプロセスがメモリ領域を確保・解放するプロセスですから、Jenkinsが使っているのだと思います。Jenkinsを使っていない時にfreeやmeminfoコマンドを使った場合と比較するとJenkinsが使っていた量が推測できるかと思います。　Jenkinsがメモリ不足で停止するとの事ですが、free -tmの出力を見るとSwapが０になっています。Swap領域(メモリが足りなくなった時、あまり使っていない部分のデータを保存しておいて、別の目的にメモリを回すために使う、ディスク上の領域）は確保されていますか？　ディスクとメモリの間でデータの読み書きが起きるのでSwapが行われるとプログラムの実行が遅くなりますが、搭載しているRAMに入りきらないプログラムでも実行できるようになります。　Swap領域を確保すれば、メモリ不足でJenkinsが停止することを避けられる（あるいは、頻度が下げられる）かと思われます。

Comment: 詳細なご説明、どうもありがとうございます。現在、Swap 領域は 0 になっています (Amazon Linux のデフォルトがそうなっていると理解しています)。

元の質問文が悪かったと思うのですが、実際には "Jenkins が停止する" というよりは、"Jenkins のジョブがメモリ不足で失敗する" というのがほとんどです (問題文は修正しました)。ジョブの種類によりますが、コンソール出力には `OutOfMemoryError` に相当するメッセージが出ます。Jenkins を再起動しても、`slabtop` では `kmalloc-256` がメモリを掴み続けているようなので、これはどうしたものかなーと思っています。

Comment: リンク先が切れてしまった場合でも回答を損なわないように重要な内容を回答に引用してください。ヘルプセンター：[リンクの文脈を提示する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)